# Dual Booting on Dell 1545 with W7 & Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot

I have been successfully dual booting the system with both W10 & W7. When I boot-up now I just get 'GRUB RESCUE'.? Several times I've recovered the boot sequence by re-loading Ubuntu from a live disk. But not this time. I would like to rescue my boot sequennce (Grub) without loosing my W7. Although I cannot access W7 or Ubuntu, booting up with live disk  (not install) I can see the disk partisions. Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: Tried the procedure from both Try Ubuntu & Ubuntu installed.  Comes back with, "cannot locate Boot Repair".  Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to run a live cd of ubuntu and install boot-repair. Open the terminal and copy and paste the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

After successfully adding and updating the repository type the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

There you can solve your issues related to boot.

Comment: Thanks  Vishnu for your fast response. Will give your procedure a run later & post the result..